# PHP: ReflectionMethod::getAttributes throwing error 'Call to undefined method'

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP (did some small projects a few years back, but nothing since) and trying to get familiar with it again by creating a RESTful API project. Coming from a C# background, I'm trying to setup the boiler plate stuff to be similar to that of .NET, where controllers handle the request and attributes help determine which function should handle the request.

The problem I'm running into is retrieving the attributes from a method within the Controller class. I create an instance of `ReflectionClass`, call `getMethods()` then attempt to iterate the methods to retrieve the attributes by calling `$method->getAttributes(HttpGet::class)` but the `$method->getAttributes()` call is throwing the following error

> 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ReflectionMethod::getAttributes() in /var/www/*********/api/base/ApiController.php:36\

Here is the code
-Running on Apache2 / Linux with PHP 7.4.28

**The Controller**

```
    require './base/ApiController.php';
    require './base/attributes/RouteAttributes.php';

    class SessionController extends ApiController
    {
        #[HttpGet('')]
        public function OnGet()
        {
            parent::OK("GET Called - Returned 200 OK");
        }

        #[HttpPost('')]
        public function OnPost()
        {
            parent::Created("POST called - Returned 201 CREATED");
        }
    }

    $controller = new SessionController();
    ApiController::HandleRequest($controller);
?>
```

**The ApiController base class**

```
    /* Base class for all API controllers, provides basic functionality like
     * returning common statuses, conversion of data to JSON and formatting 
     * appropriate headers
     */  
    require "HttpStatusCode.php";

    class ApiController 
    {
        //Return Types
        public static function StatusCode(int $status, $data)
        {
            header('X-PHP-Response-Code: $status->value', true, $status);
            if(isset($data))
            {
                header("Content-type: application/json");
                echo json_encode($data);
            }
            exit;
        }

        public static function HandleRequest($controller)
        {
            $routePath = isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO']) ? $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] : NULL;
            $requestMethod = strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);

            $controllerInfo = new ReflectionClass($controller);

            $methodFound = false;
            switch($requestMethod)
            {
                case 'GET':
                    foreach($controllerInfo->getMethods() as $method)
                    {
                        echo $method;
                         $getAttribute = $method->getAttributes(HttpGet::class);
                         if(count($getAttribute))
                         {
                             $method.invoke($controller, NULL);
                             $methodFound = true;
                         }
                    }
                    break;
                case 'POST':
                    break;

            }
            if($methodFound == false)
                ApiController::StatusCode(HttpStatusCode::NotFound, "Method Not Found");
        }


        public function OK($data)
        {
            ApiController::StatusCode(HttpStatusCode::OK, $data);
        }
        
        public function Created($data, $createdAtRoute)
        {
            if(isset($createdAtRoute))
                header('Location: $createdAtRoute');

            StatusCode(HttpStatusCode::Created, $data);
        }
        
        public function Accepted($data)
        {
            StatusCode(HttpStatusCode::Accepted, $data);
        }
        
        public function NoContent()
        {
            StatusCode(HttpStatusCode::NoContent, NULL);
        }

        public function BadRequest($data)
        {
            StatusCode(HttpStatusCode::BadRequest, $data);
        }
        
        public function Unathorized($data)
        {
            StatusCode(HttpStatusCode::Unathorized, $data);
        }
        
        public function Forbidden($data)
        {
            StatusCode(HttpStatusCode::Forbidden, $data);
        }
        
    }
?>
```

**The Attribute definitions**

```
    #[Attribute]
    class HttpGet
    {
        public string $Route;
        public function __construct(string $route)
        {
            $this->Route = $route;
        }
    }

    #[Attribute]
    class HttpPost
    {
        public string $Route;
        public function __construct(string $route)
        {
            $this->Route = $route;
        }
    }

    #[Attribute]
    class HttpPut
    {
        public string $Route;
        public function __construct(string $route)
        {
            $this->Route = $route;
        }
    }

    #[Attribute]
    class HttpPatch
    {
        public string $Route;
        public function __construct(string $route)
        {
            $this->Route = $route;
        }
    }

    #[Attribute]
    class HttpDelete
    {
        public string $Route;
        public function __construct(string $route)
        {
            $this->Route = $route;
        }
    }
?>
```

The project is very much still in the infancy stages and going to be a functional 'learner' project to get my feet wet. I just haven't been able to get past this error. Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is with the PHP version. PHP Annotations have been supported since PHP 8.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Attributes overview (PHP 8): https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.attributes.overview.php